# Passing variables to procedures versus using upvar?

Tags: tcl

Is there a cost to using `upvar` such that it ought to be used only when the objective is to have a procedure set a variable's value in a context "above" it; and not use it in lieu of passing arguments that use the value but need not set it outside of its own context?

There are a couple instances in code I'm moving to Tcl in which an argument is passed to a function that then passes it to another but doesn't use it otherwise. In Tcl, `upvar 2` makes it possible to not pass the variable at all, but I wondered how much work is involved in that, and should I just match the same passing scheme as used in functions in most langagues.

Thank you for considering my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance is not the issue. Semantics is the issue.

In theory `upvar` should have better performance than passing in values. That's because with `upvar` you're just passing the variable's name and then point to the value - essentially similar to passing a pointer/reference in other languages.

In practice it makes little to no difference because tcl does not copy values unnecessarily. Internally tcl implements copy-on-write and only pass pointers around. Tcl will perform a full copy of a value only when you attempt to write to it.

#### Semantics

The semantics is the big difference.

Many newer, modern programming languages have introduced the concept of mutability mostly inspired by pure functional languages where variables cannot change values after the first assignment. Languages like Java and Typescript for example have introduced the `final` and `const` keyword to make variables immutable. Languages like Rust have variables immutable by default and introduced the `mut` keyword to make selected variables mutable.

However there is another mechanism that tcl has that is often overlooked in other languages: changes to variables are always **local** unless you specify otherwise. That is, if you modify an argument `x` it would not affect its value in the caller's scope. This is global immutability but local mutability (I can swear there's a name for this but can't recall right now, in any case the Tcl community has never directly given a name to this feature).

I believe Apple's Swift has something similar to this but implemented slightly differntly. In Tcl it is simply the side-effect of everything-is-a-string (everything is a value). Having this strict copy semantics makes Tcl feel very functional at times and is very helpful in managing code complexity and improving clarity of code.

`Upvar` is tcl's escape mechanism for when you need the mutability to infect the caller's scope. Therefore it is wise to use it only in situations where you need mutability of that variable to infect the caller's scope (if you need the function to modify the variable in the caller's scope).

Personally I reach for `upvar` in places where I'd normally want a pointer in C/C++.

Comment: Tcl's values behave as if they are immutable... but without the performance penalties for true immutability. (The correctness of that trick ties into the threading model, which is why not many languages can do it.)